# Input Field text wrap with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I am creating an input field where I want to put the instructions for my visitors on how to proceed. The instructions will auto-hide as soon as it clicked. I could do it but I am finding the long sentences are not showing properly. I tried wrap code in css but no luck.

Here are the codes:

```css
.replybox{}
.reply-control{
border:1px solid #ccc;
background: transparent;
font-size:20px;
width:100%;
height:100px;
color:#8d8d8d;}
```

```html
<input class="reply-control" name="replybox" onblur="if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;How to wrap this text? It is hiding the overflown text. I am not finding any way. Please help&quot;;}" onfocus="if (this.value == &quot;How to wrap this text? It is hiding the overflown text. I am not finding any way. Please help&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;;}" value="How to wrap this text? It is hiding the overflown text. I am not finding any way. Please help" type="text"/>
```

`JSFiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t3tmpt0c/).

Comment: Can you use a textarea?

Comment: Are you trying to make placeholder text? Because you could easily do that (and style it) with the native placeholder tag.

Comment: But in textarea the jQuery codes will not work... it'll show actual codes

Comment: That's a placeholder. Don't reinvent the wheel!!

Comment: `<input type="text" placeholder="Your long text that will disappear when user write something and will appear again when user remove the content">`

Comment: **[`Here is it with textarea and placeholder`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t3tmpt0c/1/)**

Comment: Using a placeholder does not solve the problem of the text not wrapping. As far as I am aware, `input` elements do not *do* text wrapping. You will have to use a `textarea` instead.

Comment: You can not make second line with the input tag , if you need that then you have to create textarea or div as content editable.

Comment: @guruprasad-rao Your code has resolved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Update details of your present skin condition (e.g. normal, dry, flaky, etc). Optionally, add details of any past skin conditions, medication or skin treatments/surgeries undergone. You may also upload images/reports, so that doctors understand your condition better." value=""></textarea>
```

Comment: using place holder you can do, text will be wrapped automatically, and css/jquery property does not support for placeholder.